# Can't Access individual JSON data [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I have an external JSON file hotel.json.

```
{
    "hotel_info": [{
        "booking_id": "2",
        "hotel_name": "Ascot Lodging",
        "star_id": "2",
        "street": "Via Vincenzo da Seregno",
        "province": "Milan",
        "price_per_night": "417.00"
    }]
}
```

I'm using AngularJS to read this and display the data. 
In my controller I have:

```
app.controller('mainController', function($scope,$http) {
    $http.get('includes/hotel.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.hotel = data;
   });
});
```

I should then be able to display the data on the HTML page using:

```
<h3>{{ hotel.hotel_info.hotel_name }}</h3>
```

This should display "**Ascot Lodging**" but it doesn't display anything.

The data is being passed through because if I remove .hotel_name from the handlebars it simply returns the whole JSON text.

Does anyone know why I can't access the individual information?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: MrCode is right. If you json file has info about only one hotel i wouldnt put it in an array and instead have it as an object map: {
        "booking_id": "2",
        "hotel_name": "Ascot Lodging",
        "star_id": "2",
        "street": "Via Vincenzo da Seregno",
        "province": "Milan",
        "price_per_night": "417.00"
    }
This is essentially all you need and the interpolation would look like
{{hotel.hotel_name}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSON `hotel_info` is an array not an object (the square brackets `[]` are the array notation). Change to:

```
<h3>{{ hotel.hotel_info[0].hotel_name }}</h3>
```

Comment: Thank you, something so simple!